# disable/ enable input fields by drop down selection mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to create ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet Application, in that application I have View for Registration , According to the selection of Role It should be able to disable few input fields in registration form ,

Ex: When user select Higher Education Council , It will be able to disable "University","Direct_Number","Mobile" fields

Here my CSHTML Code including Jquery

```
@model AFFEMS2_HEC.Models.RegisterViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HEI_Registration";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HEI_Registration.cshtml";
}


}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>Add New Higher Education Institute</h2>
</hgroup>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleName,"Please Select Type of the Role ")
                <br/>
             </div>
              <div>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RoleName,
                                                      new SelectList(
                                                      new List<Object>{ 
                                                      new { value = "" , text = "Select"  },
                                                      new { value = "HEC_Admin" , text = "Higher Edcuation Council" },
                                                      new { value = "HEI_User" , text = "Higher Education Institute"}
                                                      }, "value", "text", "-"), new { id = "allDay" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleName)

                    </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>

                      <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.University)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.University ,new { id = "University" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.University)
        </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.First_Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Last_Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
        </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Direct_Number)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Direct_Number ,new { id = "Direct_Number" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Direct_Number)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile ,new { id = "Mobile" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile)
        </div>

       <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
        </div>


        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

    <script>
        $("#allDay").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "HEC_Admin") {
                $("#University").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#Direct_Number").attr("disabled", true);
                $("#Mobile").attr("disabled", true);
            }
            if ($(this).val() == "HEI_User") {
                $("#University").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#Direct_Number").attr("disabled", false);
                $("#Mobile").attr("disabled", false);
            }

        });

    </script>
}
```

Seems like it doesn't working , Appreciate someone can help

Comment: Not related, but don't do `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mobile ,new { id = "Mobile" })`. I assume you think its setting the `id` attribute, but its not (and the html helper sets it to "Mobile" anyway so even if it did work it would just be pointless)

Comment: And it should be `$("#University").prop("disabled", true);`  - `.prop` not `.attr`

Comment: can you show rendered html? seem like you have js problem and js works with razor output.

Comment: do you include Jquery Library into your project :D ? Some errors in Browser Console?

Comment: I think when we put   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval") it include Jquery Library automatically , correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @kez, only if you correctly init that bundle :D

Comment: @kez, Easy enough to check, OP would be getting errors in the console if the scripts were not loading.

Comment: its working now , thnks all , but disabled field's color are same like enable fields , how to change that?

Comment: @kez, to change color you can add your css style. Something like this : `input:disabled {
    background: #dddddd;
}`. But as i know IE9+ support this, earlier - not

Comment: How'd you go with this, @kez?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           if ($(this).val() == "HEC_Admin") {
                $("#University").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#Direct_Number").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                $("#Mobile").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            if ($(this).val() == "HEI_User") {
                $("#University").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#Direct_Number").removeAttr("disabled");
                $("#Mobile").removeAttr("disabled");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the `Scripts` section may actually render before your other content, it depends on your layout file. You should wrap the event setup in an on document load event handler.

Secondly, you want to use the `.prop()` jquery function, instead of `.attr()`. `.attr()` references only the initial state of the attribute; what was written in the HTML, basically. So replace that script with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#allDay").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "HEC_Admin") {
            $("#University").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Direct_Number").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#Mobile").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "HEI_User") {
            $("#University").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#Direct_Number").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#Mobile").prop("disabled", false);
        }

    });
});
```